# Is it possible to get Local Notification when application's state is inactive

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I'm developing an iOS application, and I have to get local notification, BUT in case of application's state is inactive. I successfully get notifications when application is in background state. 
So, is it possible to get local notification, when application is inactive?
Or maybe that's possible only by using push notification?

Regards,
Armen

Answer (score 9):

You need to respond to local notifications in two places in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

The first is for when your app was not running - use the `launchOptions` parameter to check if your app was launched due to a local notification.

The second is for when your app is currently running (active or inactive). You can check if the app is inactive by checking NSApplication's `applicationState` property in the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)sendNotification
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
//    notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.fireDate = vwPicker.date;
    localNotification.alertBody = txtAlarmTitle.text;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.userInfo = @{@"Title": txtAlarmTitle.text};
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [self handleNotification:notification application:application];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification)
        [self handleNotification:localNotification application:application];

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleNotification: (UILocalNotification *)notification application:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSString *title = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"Title"];

    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Smart Alarm" message:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Answer the Teaser" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use `willResignActiveNotification` notification listener as listed
[here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification)